# Verify user for database connection when user is logged in on app by Facebook api

Tags: php, android, ajax, facebook, cordova

Currently I'm making a Android application using Phonegap and the Facebook API. When the app starts the user needs to login using Facebook. Then I want to make calls to my own MySQL database with AJAX. But how do I verify that the user is logged in? Otherwise everybody can make calls to my database when they find the URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can send with your AJAX a security token maybe based on the user id and access_token or cookies that will ensure that it's unique to that user's session.